# How can solve this issue "cannot be considered a valid collection"

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I'm running this code below but I'm getting an error that may probably come from this line of code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
```

I found similar problems from this platform but the solutions provided don't mutch with my issue. The error shown is:

```
Singleton array array(0) cannot be considered a valid collection
```

Please assist me.

```
@permission_required('admin.can_add_log_entry')
def upload_file(request):
    template='upload_file.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template)
    CSV_file=request.FILES['csv_file']
    if not CSV_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a CSV file')
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('add_pull_requests'))
    data_set=CSV_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string=StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    dataset=csv.reader(io_string, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')
    csv_list=list(dataset)

    # prediction_dataset=[]
    for row in csv_list:
        if row[11]=='Non-Reopened':
            row[11]=0
        else:
            row[11] = 1
        if row[9]=='Rejected':
            row[9]=0
        else:
            row[9]=1
    prediction_dataset = [row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10]]
    X = [prediction_dataset]
    y = row[11]
    print(X)
    print(y)
    test_size = 0.2
    random_state = 5
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
    # clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    print(accuracy= accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100)


    return render(request, template,{"csv_list": csv_list})
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace of error. The problem seems to be in `X = [prediction_dataset]`. What do you think is happening here? What do you get when you do `print(X), print(y)`?

Comment: Singleton array array(0) cannot be considered a valid collection. This is the error that I'm getting. Sorry for forgetting to show the full stack trace of error.

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar, please any progress?

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar, y is the target column of my dataset for the prediction and X is a list of the remains columns of my dataset. So, printing these 2 lists is just to make sure they are not empty.

Comment: `prediction_dataset` is assigned outside of for-loop. So will only contain a single entry (last one from for loop). You make X using that so `X` has only a single sample. You cannot do a `train_test_split` on single row.

Comment: I got what you're saying. I noticed this problem and I put predition_dataset inside the for loop but I still get the same problem and I understand that the problem may come from the y variable as it is getting the values of the target class according to what you're saying. I checking it once more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by first, `import pandas as pd`, and then replacing this line of code `dataset=csv.reader(io_string, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')` by `dataset=pd.read_csv(CSV_file)`. So it is working now.

Thanks